# How to close only one Bootstrap Card in Angular?

Tags: angular

I implemented a card (bootstrap 4) using *ngFor

I have a couple of bottons "more" & "less" for each card, the problem comes when I click "more or less" it collapses or opens ALL the cards, how can I specify to close or to open only one the card or only the card clicked.... I know that I have to pass some ID but I don't how......any suggestion? Thanks..

[My Code Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwKAZ.png)

Comment: probably, you nedd one  more button which does that :)

Comment: Can you please share the piece of code with that ngFor. So that I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a variable collapsed in the object so you can keep track any change in each card

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let title of search; let i = index;" style="border: none;">
  <h5 class="card-title" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #979797">{{title.label}}</h5>


<div class="card-body" [ngClass]="{ test1: collapsed == true, test2: collapsed == false }">
    <div *ngIf="title.label == 'Department Name'">
        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let items of title.options  | slice : 0: 5">
            <li class="list-group py-1 border-0 item" style="text-decoration: underline black;">{{items.name}} ({{items.count}})</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!title.collapsed">
        <div>
            <div *ngIf="title.label == 'Department Name'">
                <ul class="list-group " *ngFor="let items of title.options  | slice : 5">
                    <li class="list-group py-1 border-0 item" style="text-decoration: underline black;">{{items.name}} ({{items.count}})</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div *ngIf="title.label != 'Department Name'">
        <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let items of title.options  | slice : 0: 5">
           <mat-checkbox>
            <li class="list-group py-1 border-0 item" style="text-decoration: underline black;">{{items.name}} ({{items.count}})</li>
             </mat-checkbox>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!title.collapsed">
        <div>
            <div *ngIf="title.label != 'Department Name'">
                <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let items of title.options  | slice : 5">
                   <mat-checkbox>
                    <li class="list-group py-1 border-0 item" style="text-decoration: underline black;">{{items.name}} ({{items.count}})</li>
                     </mat-checkbox>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="title.collapsed == true">
    <button class="btn btn-block " (click)="showMoreLess(i, title.collapsed)" style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline black;">More</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="title.collapsed == false">
    <button class="btn btn-block" (click)="showMoreLess(i, title.collapsed)" style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline black;">Less</button>
</div>
```